# Trying to replicate google maps slide panel with maps v3 and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

I'm trying to create a slide panel similar to the one used currently on the left hand side of maps.google.com 
The behavior I'm trying to replicate in conjunction with this panel (as displayed on google maps)

- When the panel opens the maps center will stay stationary
- The map controls (zoom, scale etc) are not overlapped by the panel, as in they'll shift with the expanding of the panel.

I initially thought I could just absolutely position a div over the map but this was covering the map controls e.g. (zoom, scale etc) and positioning them elsewhere was not an option.

My other two attempts are almost there but unfortunately not quite. Note the code examples were quickly thrown together for demo purposes.

**1st attempt:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fdwGd/5/

Two divs, one being the sliding panel and the other holding the map contents, both floated left. The 'Close'/ 'Open' button on the white panel has a click handler that animates the change of margin of the slide panel to hide it. The map div's width expands in parallel to fill the empty space. The problem here is the whole map shifts to the right when expanding the panel (click 'Open'/ 'close' in the jsfiddle example)
Positioning the panel to the right hand side of the screen resolves this ( with the addition of overflow: hidden on the html element) Although this does not meet my design requirements.

Also note that using google maps panby(x, y) function to fix the pixel jump was very clunky, so not really an option either

**2nd attempt:**

http://jsfiddle.net/63uxt/1/

So figured I'd have a go at adding a custom Google map control programmatically (the control being the sliding panel in question) and using the positioning options to get the other controls to nicely fit around my slide panel. Initially thought it worked until I realized the other controls would not re-position themselves after the sliding panel was hidden. Moving the map updated the position of the native controls (zoom etc) but this is not viable.

any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what you actually want. Do you want the map zoom/pan controls as part of the sliding panel, or do you want to shift them so that the sliding panel doesn't overlay them?

Comment: Hi Tomm, Exactly,I want them to shift so the panel doesnt overlay them. This is the behaviour of current google maps site. 
When clicking the sliding panel expand button on google maps, the map's position stays stationary and the controls (zoom, scale etc) move over to the right

Comment: (Apologies i think i may have initially posted the wrong jsfiddle above for attempt 2, its been ammended)

Anyway, The example with the panel on the right, although this doesn't meet my design requirements. http://jsfiddle.net/w6HFa/6/

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think I have this figured out.

a very basic example - http://jsfiddle.net/H87q7/3/

I've gone the custom map control route and used the 'step' callback  of Jquery's animate function to fire the google  map 'resize' event. This re-positions the controls on the map at each step of the animation which appears quite smooth.

Not sure how elegant it is, as I'd rather not use a custom google control as I have quite a number of html elements to wire up within the panel and adding them all programmatically isn't what I'd like to do, but anyway...

I'd love to hear opinions on alternative ways of doing this.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this Stephen it has helped a lot. However once I implemented your sliding panel all of my info windows resized to the default. Before, the info window had a height of about 500px now it is only about 200px. Any ideas?